# How to sql query only once insert on android

Tags: android, sql-server

I want `A` table only once insert sql query.

before insert query. if my `A` table have 1 record. execute update 1 record.

and my `A` table have 0 record. insert query.

I know only use insert query.

```
public class compareInsert extends Thread {

    private Connection mConnection = null;
    private Statement mStatement = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
       super.run();

       Looper.prepare();
       setDB();
       Looper.loop();
    } 

    public void setDB() {
          mConnection = DBconnect.connectJDBC(); // DB Connect.

          try {
              mStatement = mConnection.createStatement();
              mStatement.executeQuery("use be");

              String insertq = "insert into A"
                       + "(name, old, num)"
                       + "values"
                       + "(?, ?, ?);
             PreparedStatement statement = mConnect.prepareStatement(insertq);
             statement.setString(1, "hyunwook");
             statement.setString(2, "17");
             statement.setString(3, "2732");

             int ret = statement.executeUpdate();
             if (ret > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS");
             } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed");
             }
          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
               try {
                    mConnection.close();
               } catch (Exception e) {
               }
          }
      }
   }
```

this source is insert query code.
but app start, always insert query.

please help for me

thanks.

Comment: Use Insert or Replace query and add iD type column in your table it will help you to achieve your req.